# What if the meaning of that expression if(x > y / z)

Tags: java, if-statement

I always know that if statement must have boolean expression.
but i saw this

```
if(x > y / z){
System.out.println("That is Correct ") ; 
}
```

Is not  `x>y` boolean expression and `/z` mathematical operator ?!
how does this work . knowing that x , y and z are type `int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `x > (y / z)`. The expression `y / z` returns a number which is being compared to `x`.

[The operator precedence table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) explains why it works even without round brackets.

```
┌────────────────┬───────────────────────────────┐
│   Operators    │          Precedence ↓         │
├────────────────┼───────────────────────────────┤
│ multiplicative │ * / %                         │
│ relational     │ < > <= >= instanceof          │ 
└────────────────┴───────────────────────────────┘
```

A simple example

```
System.out.println((10 == 20 / 2) ? "correct" : "incorrect");
```

prints

> correct

Comment: You beat me by seconds but it's worth mentioning operator precedence to help OP.

Comment: @paisanco sure, I was drawing an ascii table ;)

Answer (score 0):

It just comes down to order of operations. The integer division takes precedence over the relational comparison. It equates to

```
if(x > (y / z))
```

You can learn more about operator precedence [here.](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/)

As you can see in the table at that link, relational operators have a precedence of 9 while mathematical operators have a precedence of 12, so they execute first because their precedence is higher.

Answer (score 0):

According to BODMAS rule ---> Division come first from multiplication.
Same in java the precedence of / is higher than * so Division happen first then multiplication.

Comment: According to the Java language spec, which is what applies here: *The multiplicative operators have the same precedence and are syntactically left-associative (they group left-to-right).*   [JLS 15.17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7).  Doesn't seem to be relevant to the original question, which has no multiplication.